# What's the minimal conda environment build for pandas?

Tags: pandas, conda, miniconda

I'm using Miniconda 3, and I'm trying to build a minimal Conda environment containing `pandas`. However, when I try to load the `pandas` module, Jupyter gives me the following error:

*The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.*

When doing the same thing via Python in the Terminal, Python crashes.

I have created a minimal Conda environment, which can be reproduced via the code below.

```
conda create -n testenv
conda activate testenv
conda install python
conda install pandas
conda install jupyter
```

The problem doesn't occur anymore when I follow up with a full Anaconda install, via `conda install anaconda`.

Any ideas as to how this problem can be resolved without installing Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. What I should have mentioned is that I built a global channel list according to Bioconda recommendation, using

```
conda config --add channels defaults
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

This makes `conda-forge` the highest-priority channel. For reasons I don't understand, `conda-forge` builds a dependency hell. (I noticed the guys at conda-forge: https://github.com/conda-forge/pandas-feedstock/issues/63).

For now, install using `conda install -c defaults pandas`.